# Access elements of 2D list

Tags: python, indexing, data-structures

I have a list of variables in python and I would like to be able to access the index of individual values in each row and column. Because I am new to python, I do not know if there is another way to access the index or select individual values by row and column.

The only way I have found so far is to use the pandas library, but I cannot use pandas because of a problem in installation. Please advise me on how to create a dataframe(without using pandas) or any other data structure so that I can access its values by their index, by row and column.

Let's say I have the following list: (Actually when I try to find the data structure type, python says it is a list.

```
(['Name'    'Age'        'Smoking'   'Grade']) 

(['Joh'      23           'No'         90])

(['Zak'      25           'No'         89])

(['Suz'      24           'Yes'        80])

(['Sus'      26           'Yes'        83])
```

Let's say we name it "habits"

I would like to access individual values, such as habits[3,2] and I would like to have the result as 80 which is located at the 3rd index of rows and at the 2nd index of columns.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a list.

Comment: That looks like 5 separate lists, with each list containing a string; in Python, adjacent string literals are concatenated. Are you reading this data from a file?

Comment: Yes I am reading from a file. The above data is just an example.                   I converted them to list of lists as advised in the comments, but still I cannot access individual values. I can only print the whole lists at once.

Comment: You could post a question regarding the pandas error. Your question doesn't contain a list of lists. It contains 5 tuples, each with *one element* of a 4 element list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a list of lists.

This is how you can make one:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow']]
data.append(['elephant', 'donkey', 'cat'])
```

This is how you access its contents:

```
data[0]  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
data[0][0]  # 1
data[1][2]  # 'red'
```